# How do I display questions in blocks?

Tags: 7, quiz

How can I display questions in a block using the Quiz module?

I do it using the Views module, but when I click on *Start quiz*, it goes to a page. I want all functionality done inside a block.

Comment: Though now 3 years old, the Quiz FAQ addresses this question: https://www.drupal.org/node/507090#1

Answer (score 1):

Though now 3 years old, the Quiz FAQ addresses this question: drupal.org/node/507090#1

### How do I create a quiz block?

Quiz 3.x has the Views module integration. To create a quiz block showing the top scorers or recent quiz you can use the Views module [to expose as a block]